# The drill bits in my SDS drill don't slide up and down 15mm in the chuck

Tags: drill, drill-bit

Drill bits are meant to slide up and down within the chuck. In my new drill there's about 2mm of in/out movement in the chuck. (There's about 1cm if movement from the whole chuck, but I don't think that's where the movement is meant to come from.)

I haven't tested it yet, but as I don't know what to reasonably expect from an SDS drill I wouldn't know what OK or good drill performance would look like.

Should I send it back to the shop?

Comment: Make/model of drill?

Comment: Have you lubed it? SDS chucks need lube. Performance-wise, that’ll depend on the make & model. Even then, the only real test is whether it makes holes in stone.

Comment: Oh, and where did you get your 15mm number? That’s unusually high for a drill that isn’t running.

Comment: This is the drill... https://amzn.eu/d/ehnQWa4               The 15mm reference comes from here:  https://youtu.be/tYUvlxWkFh8#t=2m40s

Comment: (YouTube video isn't jumping to 2m40s with that link, but it should be.)

Comment: YouTube code is &t=2m40s, not # making the link https://youtu.be/tYUvlxWkFh8&t=2m40s

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin.  (Sorry if this message breaks the rules.)

Answer (score 4):

Test after spinning the drill up a couple of times. Sometimes they just come to rest with the hammer mechanism 'closed'.

Drill a hole, listen to it.
If it whines like a cheap DIY drill, send it back. If it thumps like it should, keep it. If it has a hammer only 'chisel' setting, test that too.

Comment: I did think that might be the explanation (about the drill being switched off with the hammer action at the start or end of it's stroke) . Will test, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a question about your drill after it's been in the shop, ask them, not us. Take it back to the shop. They know the drill better than we do and will instruct you on its use which is something else we can't do.

Comment: True for a DIY/hardware store. Not true for Amazon.

Comment: (Also shops generally don't like giving refunds.)

Comment: @TheOnlyRick  You never said anything about Amazon, just the shop.  You led us to believe there was something not right and you didn't know what to expect or how to use it and asked if you should sent it back. Thus my answer.  :-)

Comment: Apols, I forgot I used the word 'shop'. That word certainly doesn't suggest 'Amazon'.  (To answer my original question... The drill certainly works, if Anthony a bit too well.  I really need to tense up against it before squeezing the trigger, otherwise I'll end demolishing walls rather than making a hole to take a 6mm screw...  